# Unable to change password

Tags: windows, windows-8, passwords

I'm unable to change my (admin) password in Windows 8 or to disable password login altogether.

Here's what I tried so far:

- Go to the PC-Settings>User in the Metro UI. If I try to change the password there I get an error message:
  Something went wrong, please log out and back in. Doing so does not help, I get the same message again.
  And toggling whether to use a password for login does nothing as well
- In the control panel>login information my account is listed under generic login. Editing the password here does nothing.
- Disabling the password via Win+r 'netplwiz' does nothing.

Note that the password I create during the Windows 8 installation still works for logging in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried it via the command line? Open an elevated command prompt and type:

```
net user your_username new_password
```

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt, type in `control userpasswords2` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Dutch, a good answer needs more detail. Try to tell the questioner what they're doing wrong, why they should do it your way, etc.